# magento 1.9 signup form

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have been cracking my head about this for two days on. I inherited some magento 1.9 Multi vendor website and just need to bolden some text on the customer create account field. I have searched every where in my template directory Customer/form/register.phtml and Persitent/form/register.phtml yet I am not successfully able to identify the line that prints

'wants to become a vendor?'
Here is a link to the form please.
http://store.min-trade.com/index.php/customer/account/create/

Could someone point me in the right direction. I pretty much understand the project structure of Magento I do believe. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking in the correct template folder?

You are using the rwd/default template, so have a look here;
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

If there isn't a file called register.phtml in that location, then Magento will fall back to the base folder, so try;

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

If you still cannot find the text, it could be a custom login form using another template. Login to your server with ssh/putty and run this command;

```
grep -nr 'Wants to become a Vendor?' /path/to/magento/*
```

Just make sure you set the correct path.

Comment: You are the best. grep -nr 'Wants to become a Vendor?' /path/to/magento/* did the trick. it turned out it was a widget the coder used there. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check by enabling path hints from magento admin.
If you dont know how to enable file path hint then refer this link  [enter link description here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-template-path-hints-magento/)

second thing that if you have installed any vendor extension then register form will be displayed from that module.

You can also install this [path hint module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html) for check file.